# apt-get upgrade stalls

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I had an issue with list.sources file. Now that's resolved and I'm wondering how can I make sure that it's safe to apt-get upgrade and dist-upgrade the system?

```
s2:/var# aptitude upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
open: 4669; closed: 6206; defer: 0; conflict: 0                                  ^C
```

This was stalling and casued a problem until I fixed the sources.list file. New sources file:

```
s2:/etc/apt# cat sources.list
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

apt-get update and upgrade now works and I get this

```
apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... 
(skip list of packages)
The following packages will be upgraded:
(skip list of packages)
214 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
Need to get 117 MB of archives.
After this operation, 8,295 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

How can I make sure this its safe to proceed?

System info:

```
s2:/etc/apt# uname -a
Linux ns2 3.2.0-4-powerpc #1 Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 ppc GNU/Linux

ns2:/etc/apt# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 8 \n \l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this first:

```
apt-get-f install
```

Now carry on with the apt-get update and upgrade. Honestly not much can go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure this its safe to proceed?

Why do you believe it isn't?  I don't see anything unusual there at all.

In other words, just hit enter and proceed.  It may take a few minutes, but 114 MB worth of archives isn't that much.